# Правильное употребление наречия «матово»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов

В одном тексте мне попалось выражение "её ноги матово блестели".
Но ведь "матовый" означает "неблестящий". Написала об этом автору, но автор утверждает, что в выборе прав. А вы как думаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действительно, первое значение слова *матовый* – *неблестящий*. Но есть и другие значения (Большой толковый словарь, [Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)):

> **1. МАТОВЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. **1.** Не имеющий блеска, глянца. *М-ая поверхность стола. М. капот автомобиля. М. фарфор.* <...> **4.** Неяркий, мягкий (о свете, **блеске** и т.п.). *М. свет лампы. **М. блеск** луны. М-ое освещение.* < **Матово,** ***нареч.*** (4 зн.). ***М. блестеть.***

[Предложения со словосочетанием «матово блестеть»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C):

*Они не успевают высохнуть и **матово блестят**, отражая небо*
(Игорь Зотиков, Зимние солдаты, 2010).
*Кожа его была абсолютно чёрного цвета, без единого волоса и **матово блестела** под солнцем* (Владимир Лосев, Защитник демонов, 2005).

Мне почему-то не нравится выражение «её ноги матово блестели»...
Но, как говорится, хозяин – барин.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Александр, за столь развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: Устроило, Александр, вполне. Просто встречается в литературе много странного и неожиданного, а я, как ребёнок, хочу "разломать " игрушку и посмотреть, как она устроена )))

Comment: @Мария Спасибо за вопрос и оценку!